# Returning object with pointer in it

Tags: object, pointers

I have created this simple object in C++:

```
class Array
{
    int Size;
    int * pArr;

public:
    explicit Array(int InSize = 0)
    {
        Size=InSize;
        if (Size) 
            pArr = new int[Size];
        else 
            pArr = NULL;
    }

    Array(const Array & InArray)
    {       
        Size=InArray.Size;
        if (Size)
            pArr=new int[Size];
        else
            pArr=NULL;
    }

    ~Array()
    {
        if (pArr)
        {
            delete []pArr;
            Size=0;
        }     
    }
};
```

I am trying to overload the + operator in the following manner:

```
Array operator+(const Array &LOpArray,const Array &ROpArray)
{
    int MinSize=LOpArray.Size<ROpArray.Size ? LOpArray.Size : ROpArray.Size ;
    Array ResArray;

    if (LOpArray.Size<ROpArray.Size)
        ResArray=ROpArray;
    else
        ResArray=LOpArray;
    for (int i=0;i<MinSize;i++)
        ResArray.pArr[i]=LOpArray.pArr[i]+ROpArray.pArr[i];
    return(ResArray);
}
```

Assignment is defined as:

```
Array& Array::operator=(const Array &ROpArray)
{
    if (pArr!=ROpArray.pArr)
    {          
        Size=ROpArray.Size;
        pArr=new int[Size];
        for (int i=0;i<Size;i++)
            pArr[i]=ROpArray.pArr[i];
    }
    return (*this);
}
```

The problem is when I use it like :

```
Array A1(20),A2(8),A4;

....//initializing pointer contents

A4=A1+A2;
```

then A4 has correct values (i.e. size=20 and **new**,non NULL, int pointer)
but all the pointed values have garbage values.
debugging showed that in the operator+ function values are actually correct
but they are deleted when returning from the operator+ function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your post for formatting. I've done the first few lines to show you what it's supposed to look like. Don't use tabs.

Comment: I have re-edited it....or so I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems:

1. The copy constructor fails to copy the data.
2. `operator=` leaks memory (this doesn't have anything to do with your problem, but is worth fixing).

Comment: 1.Have fixed copy constructor - it's solved the problem....Thanx!!! 2.What do you mean by "leaks memory"?